# How does this passing of an array to "qsort" work?

Tags: c, string

So I have the main function declared below, to which the user must pass arguments from the command line when first executing the program. Then, it takes the `*argv[]` array of string inputs and sorts them using the `stdlib.h`'s qsort function, after which it finally prints out all elements, besides the file name, in the input array;

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){                                                                                                                                                                                                
  qsort(argv,args,sizeof(*argv),comp_func);
  for(int U=1;U<argc;U++)printf("%s\n",argv[U]);                                                                                                                                                                                              
}
```

The `comp_func` function passed to `qsort` is shown below:

```
int comp_func(char*a,char*b){
  return strcmp(*(char **)a,*(char **)b);
}
```

What I would like to know is what is going on here? I am pretty that `qsort` sends each 2-length permutation of the array to the given comparator function, both of which are, in this case, strings since `argv` is an array of strings. However, what I don't get is what is going on here:

```
strcmp(*(char **)a,*(char **)b)
```

What is `*(char **)a` doing? Is it just creating an arbitrary `char[]` array of a pointer to an arbitrary string with a length of 1, whose first value is then assigned the `a`, after which it is finally dereferenced, ultimately returning the string `a`?  If so, then why doesn't just plain old `a` work? Also, interestingly, if I `printf` just plain old `a`, it outputs a string of random characters that goes something like `??O_?`. However, when I printf `*(char **)a` instead, I get the actual string input. Why is that? I am a beginner in `C`, so please bear with me if I ask any more questions.

Comment: From the looks of it, i think the signature of the comp_func is wrong. Each element of the array are of type char*, so the cast is compensating for the wrong signature.

Comment: @S.C.Madsen What do you mean by `signature`? Sorry if that may seem like a dumb question, but again, I am a just a beginner in `C`, so I don't know all of the terms yet.

Comment: see my answer for 'signature'. the pattern of a comp_func typically takes (**a,**b) or "pointer to pointer". most common is void*, which basically just says its a generic pointer, and depends on a "cast" to define what the pointer actually points to

Comment: Maybe its the wrong word, but I mean the types and number of arguments (and the type of the return value) of the function.

Comment: @S.C.Madsen Well, I used the type `char*` because `qsort` was passing arguments of type `char*` anyways. However, even if I used `void *`, the same behavior results.

Comment: @R.Kap `qsort()` actually passes object of type `const char **` to `comp_func()`.. But since you don't have generics/templates, the compile time type is still `const void *`.

Answer (score 4):

`qsort()` expects a consecutive array of objects as first argument `base`. Now, `argv` is an array of `const char *` pointers, so

```
qsort(argv, args, sizeof(*argv), comp_func);
```

says, sort that array of pointers, where `sizeof(*argv)` is the size of a `const char *`.

What gets passed to `comp_func()`, is the address of two objects offset from the base pointer, i.e. the addresses of the char pointers in `argv`. To get the actual string array/pointer back that contains the argument string, we need to de-reference it. That is, the argument strings are actually at `*a` and `*b`.

The signature is still all wrong and should throw compiler warnings all over the place. `comp_func()` actually takes two `const void *`:

```
int
comp_func(const void *a,const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*(const char **)a,*(const char **)b);
}
```

The casts are necessary, since `*a` is not a valid type with `const void *` and `strcmp()` needs `const char *`, too.

Answer (score 2):

tldr; its a type-cast followed by a deference.

the typical form of a compare function is

```
int comp_func(void *a, void *b)
```

`(char**)a` casts a into pointer to char*, in this case its actually pointer to the start of the char array.

`*(char**)a` then dereferences it, meaning the pointer to start of array is passed to the `strcmp()` function.

`printf` takes pointer to start of array to print from that pointer onwards until the pointer points to a char '\0' in the array. the gibberish is because it was passed a pointer to pointer, so you get an memory address printed instead.

Comment: So `??O_?` is a memory address?

Comment: it depends. if u told printf that its printing a char array and pass it a pointer, it will print from that pointer (and then keep moving the pointer by 1 character size) FOREVER until it hits a '\0' character, or a set of zeroes in memory the size of a character.

Answer (score 2):

First of all the compare function should be

```
int comp_func(const void* a, const void* b)
```

Then try to analyze the code: you are passing to that function `argv` that is decalred as `char *argv[]`, that can be seen as `char **`

So inside the function, you must cast the generic void pointer to the root type `char **`.

Then you have to dereference to the element of the `array of pointers` that you want to compare, so: `*(char **)`

Comment: And plain old `a` does not work because `a` is already a pointer. So basically, if I am understanding this, what `*(char **)a`  does is extract the actual string from the pointer `a`, and `a` is a pointer to that string from the input array.

Comment: @R.Kap Yes, more or less. `qsort()` gives you pointers to the elements from the base "array". But the base array is an array of char pointers, so you really do get `const char **`. To get to the actual char arrays with the arguments, you need to dereference the pointer.